# Want to send email from java applications asynchronously

Tags: java, spring, email, jms

In my project i need to send emails for account activation after signup. Also need to send other emails also on some events. Can any one help me how to achieve this asynchronously. Do I need to use @Async on method that sends emails in application  or i need to create some JMS component which receive jms message from application component and send emails. Please suggest me how to solve this.

Regards,

Comment: create a new thread

Comment: In my previous app i saved emails in db and sent it by scheduler. I used [JavaMailSenderImpl](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mail/javamail/JavaMailSenderImpl.html) and [@Scheduled](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html) annotation on method that query db and send remaining emails. IMO `@Async` is ok to do that, too. Nice tutorial about @Async is [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/).

Comment: Could use futures, there good, google em.

Answer (score 0):

Write a Service class for email sender and add a @Async annotation on the method which triggers the email.

Suppose your component is triggering an email

```
@Controller
public class OrderController {

@Autowired
private MailSenderUtilityService mailSenderUtilityService;

       @RequestMapping("/setShippingAddress")
       private String sendAnEmail(Model model, Order order, User user){
            ..... Your code goes here .....

       mailSenderUtilityService.sendYourEmail(Order order, User user, Locale english);

         return "emailSent";
        }
    }





@Service
public class MailSenderUtilityService {


        @Autowired
        private JavaMailSender mailSender;

        @Autowired
        private MailConstructor mailContructor;

        @Async
        public void sendOrderSubmittedEmail(Order order, User user, Locale english) {

            CompletableFuture<MimeMessagePreparator> email = mailContructor.constructSimpleOrderPlacedEmail(order, user, Locale.ENGLISH);       
            try {
                System.out.println("********************* SLEEPING NOW FOR TESTING PURPOSE **********************");
                Thread.sleep(60000);
                mailSender.send(email.get());
            } catch (MailException | InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }       
        }
}

@Component
public class MailConstructor {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Autowired
    private TemplateEngine templateEngine;

    @Async
    public CompletableFuture<MimeMessagePreparator> constructSimpleOrderPlacedEmail(Order order, User user, Locale locale) {

        Context context = new Context();
        context.setVariable("order", order);
        context.setVariable("user", user);
        context.setVariable("cartItemList", order.getCartItemList());
        String text = templateEngine.process("orderConfirmationEmailTemplate", context);

        MimeMessagePreparator messagePreparator = new MimeMessagePreparator() {

            @Override
            public void prepare(MimeMessage mimeMessage) throws Exception {
                MimeMessageHelper email = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage);
                email.setTo(user.getEmail());
                email.setFrom(new InternetAddress("abhibookstore123@gmail.com"));
                email.setSubject("Order Confirmation - "+ order.getId());
                email.setText(text, true);              
            }
        };

        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(messagePreparator);
    }
```

This will trigger your email Asynchronously. It will not wait for 60 seconds to respond until email is sent.

Code execution in your controller will move forward and email will be triggered after 60 seconds.

Here you can find the complete example- [here](https://github.com/cfaddict/spring-boot-intro/tree/master/guides/sending-email-async)

Answer (score 0):

In Addition to @Abhinavece's answer you will have to enable Async in application

```
@SpringBootApplication
**@EnableAsync**
public class SpringPrimeFacesApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(SpringPrimeFacesApplication.class, args);
  }

  @Bean
  SessionRegistry sessionRegistry() { 
      return new SessionRegistryImpl(); 
  }

  @Bean
  public ActiveUserStore activeUserStore(){
      return new ActiveUserStore();
  }
}
```